# Android MediaStore-Downloads Cannot Access Audio Files

Tags: java, android, mediastore

Trying to access the audio files inside the MediaStore-Downloads collection. But the API does not allow any specific access to the audio files. Here is the code, but it does not return anything.

```
protected ArrayList getAudioFiles() {
    ArrayList<String> audio = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Downloads.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME },
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        audio.add(name);
    }
    return audio;
}
```

Output:

```
E/musicplayer: Audio files:
E/musicplayer: end of results.
```

Also added permission tag in the application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My question is, even if I forget that I actually wanted to query for audio files, why does the query return nothing even when I know there are files in the downloads folder?

Comment: Requesting permissions at runtime too?

Comment: Not requesting any runtime permissions, let me fix that and see.